# Python get x.x data from JSON

Tags: python, json

My JSON data looks like this (for example):

{
"data":
1:
**"name": "Stackoverflow"**
}

I want to get the highlighted data but I don't know how to do it. If I use print(json["singledata"]), it works. But if I use print(json["multiple": "datas"]), then it does not works. How can I get the multiple data?

Comment: That's not valid JSON. Please [edit] your question and post a [mre].

Comment: Np. Found the answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Found the answer! Just use like that:

data1 = json["data"]

print(type(data1["name"]))

Comment: What does `type` have to do with anything you mentioned in your question?

Comment: <class 'float'> (btw i'm getting a number)

Comment: You said you wanted the highlighted data. That's not the type of anything.

Comment: You may have solved whatever problem you had, but neither your question nor the posted answer will be of use to anyone else on Stack Overflow. Either clarify the question, or delete it.